# Wii games for a child with motor impairment

Tags: game, health, accessibility, fitness, wii

I have a 4-year old child with motor impairment, and recently came across several papers regarding how playing Wii games can yield improvements in dexterity, limb coordination, balance and motor proficiency, such as [[1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/22207475/)] [[2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/23827983/)].

What I'm looking for is recommendations for games that would be suitable. Requirements:

1. Ideally, to begin with at least, the games should be playable using only movement of the controller (without the buttons)
2. I'm also interested in games that use only the 'nunjuks'
3. Games must not be too fast paced

As an example, the *Wii Sports: Tennis* game fits the first requirement, but it is too fast paced.

Comment: It hard to find even some PC games which mets your needs nevertheless I suggest you to find / buy another device.

Comment: @onurcano22 the device specifically being a Wii is the whole point of my question - it gets you moving around, balancing, and exercising different muscle groups. It's what was used in the papers I linked to

Comment: Did the papers mention any particular games? Could you contact their authors?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the totally underrated physics game Boom Blox, [Boom Blox - youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1a1pkl2aGr8)

It is a fun game that uses the nunjuks and can be single player and multiplayer, (either working together or against others).

It is now 10 years old but it is still a great game and it should meet your requirements.

Comment: This is maybe a tad on the complex side, since it looks like you have to be quite precise with the controller - this does look like a lot of fun tho, so I'll definitely give it a try!

Comment: I really hope you like it. Give a go and let us know what you think.